# How to Create Restricted "View" for Document Library in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: document-library, permissions, view

I want to create a custom view in a document library that only certain people can see. Is it possible?

Scenario: I want to view certain columns I use for calculated values to do analytical tasks. I don't want normal end users to see this view and get confused and ask questions about things they don't know. Best approach is to hide the 'view' or restrict it to the group that develops analytical views.

So, is restricted views possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of views do not exist in SharePoint. What you can do is:

1. Create a **web part page**
2. Add a Web Part that displays the list (a **view**)
3. Then you add **permissions** individually to the **page**.

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: That's what I thought as a work-around. Egh! Microsoft has so many "no we can't do that out of the box" issues.

Comment: Yes it is a work-around, no out of the box solution for this :-(